# Private Librariesが消えてしまいました｡

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

Eclipseで新規にプロジェクトと作ったのですが､画像のようにエラーがでてしまいました｡  プロジェクトを見てみると､今までに作ったプロジェクトにはあった､Private Librariesがありませんでした｡[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

1番上のエラーである｡`import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;`のエラーには｢インポートされた android.support.v7.app は見つかりません｣と書かれていました｡

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipseの場合、`ActionBarActivity`を使うには同じワークスペースのプロジェクトに、[`v7 support library`](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)が必要です。詳細についてはリンク先を参照して下さい。

ADTの以前のバージョンでは新規プロジェクトを作る度に、自動で最新版をインポートして新規プロジェクトと紐付けていたのですが、現在は手動でインポートしてビルドパスの解決を行う必要があるみたいですね。

```
android-sdk>extras>android>support>v7>appcompat
```

を`Import>Existing Android Code Into Workspace`からインポートして、新規に作成したプロジェクトの`Properties>Android>Library`から参照するようにします。

今まで作成されたプロジェクトには`Private Libraries`があったとのことですので、既にワークスペースに存在して利用できる可能性もあります。ただし最新のリビジョンを利用しているかどうか注意してください。

このとき、`v7-appcompat`と新規プロジェクトの間で、`android-support-v4.jar`のバージョンが違うと、ビルドエラーになります。

大抵は`v7-appcompat`側のバージョンが古いのが原因のため、そちらのプロジェクトで右クリックしてコンテキストメニューを表示して、`Android Tools>Add Support Library`で最新の`v4 support library`を取得すれば解決すると思います。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます｡  1番下の教えて頂いた方法で､新しい方のプロジェクトのエラーは直りましたが､今度は新しい方のプロジェクトで同じようなエラーが出てしまいました｡

Comment: 再起動したところ直りました｡ ありがとうございました｡